# Building Data Structure for UITableView sections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'd like to organize meetups by date sections in a UITableView

I have an array of meetups

```
class Meetup {
  var title: String
  var date: String
}
```

And a meetup section struct

```
struct MeetupSection {
    var date: String
    var meetups: [Meetup]

    init(dateString: String, meetupArray: [Meetup]) {
        date = dateString
        meetups = meetupArray
    }
}
```

And an algorithm that builds more sections than it should.

```
func buildDateMeetupDict(meetups: [Meetup]) -> [MeetupSection] {

    var meetupSections = [MeetupSection]()

    for meetup in meetups {
        if meetupSections.isEmpty {
            let newMeetupSection = MeetupSection(dateString: meetup.day, meetupArray: [meetup])
            meetupSections.append(newMeetupSection)
        } else {
            for var meetupSection in meetupSections {
                if meetup.day == meetupSection.date {
                    meetupSection.meetups.append(meetup)
                } else {
                    let newMeetupSection = MeetupSection(dateString: meetup.day, meetupArray: [meetup])
                    meetupSections.append(newMeetupSection)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return meetupSections
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: I realized your sections will be by date, so the parsing is not necessary, you can simply check to see if that specific date already has its own section.

You will have to tweak this a little to meet your needs, but basically parse out the month and year from the single date string and record them as separate variables. The entire array is sorted by date. Each date is checked to see if its month/year already has a section. If yes, add it to that section. If not, create a new section.

```
meetups.sortInPlace { $0.backwardDate < $1.backwardDate }

var tableViewSections = [MeetupSection]()

let months = [01: "January", 02: "February", 03 : "March", 04 : "April", 05 : "May", 06 : "June", 07 : "July", 08 : "August", 09 : "September", 10 : "October", 11 : "November", 12 : "December"]

var previousMonth = -1

var previousYear = -1

for meetup in meetups {

    if (meetup.year  != previousYear || meetup.month  != previousMonth) {

        var sectionHeading: String

        if meetup.month != 0 {
            sectionHeading = months[meetup.month]!
        }
        else {
           sectionHeading = ""
        }

    tableViewSections.append(MeetupSection(date, meetups: [Meetups])

    previousYear = meetup.year
    previousMonth = meetup.month

    for var section in tableViewSections {
        if section.month == meetup.month && section.year == meetup.year {

            section.dates.append(meetup)
        }
    }

}

return tableViewSections
```